# Converting to binary truncates bits

Tags: python

When trying to create a random 256 bit number the input gets truncated (Sometimes to 252 bits, others to 254). MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)
```

Example:

```
>>> private_key = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32))
>>> len(bin(int(private_key, 16))[2:])
256
>>> private_key = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32))
>>> len(bin(int(private_key, 16))[2:])
252
>>> private_key = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32))
>>> len(bin(int(private_key, 16))[2:])
256
```

Comment: @vaultah That sounds like it should be an answer (maybe with another sentence or two of explanation)

Comment: Short example: `len(bin(1)[2:])` > `1`. (Incidentally, the values `1` and `2` are the only ones in which their length is the number itself again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vaulath said in the comments, `bin` truncates to the shortest representation with no leading zeros. So if a number has 2 zeros at the beginning it would only have 254 bits. You can also see this very easily:

```
>>> bin(int("001001", 2))[2:]
'1001'
>>> len("001001")
6
>>> len(bin(int("001001", 2))[2:])
4
```

If you want the full 256 bits, you could to this:

```
>>> len(format(0,"0256b"))
256
```

Comment: @vaultah I didn't known this was possible, thanks. I edited the answer.